# How to get value of column while performing groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi I have a dataframe with datetime and high and low during the period. for eg. its 5 minutes data call it df

|  | Datetime | High | Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-02 09:15:00 | 590.349976 | 584.299988 |
| 1 | 2020-12-02 09:20:00 | 593.900024 | 588.750000 |
| 2 | 2020-12-02 09:25:00 | 594.900024 | 592.450012 |
| 3 | 2020-12-02 09:30:00 | 593.849976 | 591.799988 |
| 4 | 2020-12-02 09:35:00 | 594.400024 | 592.200012 |
| 5 | 2020-12-02 09:40:00 | 596.250000 | 593.099976 |
| 6 | 2020-12-02 09:45:00 | 596.849976 | 593.102476 |
| 7 | 2020-12-02 09:50:00 | 595.400024 | 592.950012 |
| 8 | 2020-12-02 09:55:00 | 596.500000 | 594.500000 |

I perform a groupby function to convert the 5 minutes to 15 minutes and get following output.

|  | Datetime | High | Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-02 09:15:00 | 594.900024 | 584.299988 |
| 1 | 2020-12-02 09:30:00 | 596.250000 | 591.799988 |
| 2 | 2020-12-02 09:45:00 | 596.849976 | 592.950012 |

Is it possible while performing groupby function to also get exact datetime of high and low in following desired output.

|  | Datetime | High | Low | High datetime | Low Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-02 09:15:00 | 594.900024 | 584.299988 | 2020-12-02 09:25:00 | 2020-12-02 09:15:00 |
| 1 | 2020-12-02 09:30:00 | 596.250000 | 591.799988 | 2020-12-02 09:40:00 | 2020-12-02 09:30:00 |
| 2 | 2020-12-02 09:45:00 | 596.849976 | 592.950012 | 2020-12-02 09:45:00 | 2020-12-02 09:50:00 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `group` the dataframe by [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with a frequency of `15min` and aggregate using dictionary containing the aggregation functions:

```
d = {'High': ('High', 'max'), 'Low': ('Low', 'min'),
     'High date': ('High', 'idxmax'), 'Low date': ('Low', 'idxmin')}

df.set_index('Datetime').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15min')).agg(**d)
```

---

```
                     High        Low        High date           Low date
Datetime                                                                           
2020-12-02 09:15:00  594.900024  584.299988 2020-12-02 09:25:00 2020-12-02 09:15:00
2020-12-02 09:30:00  596.250000  591.799988 2020-12-02 09:40:00 2020-12-02 09:30:00
2020-12-02 09:45:00  596.849976  592.950012 2020-12-02 09:45:00 2020-12-02 09:50:00
```

Comment: I am getting this errors. 'ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence'

Comment: @AnimeshShah  i guess the error is occurring due to presence of empty groups, while we use `pd.Grouper`..because both `idxmax` and `idxmin` expects the groups to be `non-empty`. One idea to solve this problem is you can first ensure that all the `5 mins` data points are present..Check with `df.set_index('Datetime').asfreq('5min').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15min')).agg(**d)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Datetime ']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime '])
df=df.set_index('Datetime ')
df1=df.resample('15T').max().reset_index()
df2=df.resample('15T').min().reset_index()

df1['High Datetime ']=df1[['High ']].merge(df.reset_index(),how='left')['Datetime ']
df1['Low Datetime ']=df2[['Low']].merge(df.reset_index(),how='left')['Datetime ']
```

Output:

```
df1
Out[51]: 
            Datetime        High   ...      High Datetime        Low Datetime 
0 2020-12-02 09:15:00  594.900024  ... 2020-12-02 09:25:00 2020-12-02 09:15:00
1 2020-12-02 09:30:00  596.250000  ... 2020-12-02 09:40:00 2020-12-02 09:30:00
2 2020-12-02 09:45:00  596.849976  ... 2020-12-02 09:45:00 2020-12-02 09:50:00

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: merge function lot of issues due to duplicate values. I tried that. i want a datetime value that is within the range of time. It should match high and also consider that date is within the timerange to return the value. for eg. in above series high time is 9.25, which is within the range of 09:15-09:29 and hence proper

Comment: Yes. @ShubhamSharma 's answer is better and fast !